# Codeigniter - redirect http to https except one page (Amazon ELB)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon ELB with HTTPS (ELB redirect all traffic from 443 to 80)  and everything working great.

Now I using the next htaccess code to redirect all the request from http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and its working great, the problem is that Amazon ELB health check failed because of the http to the https redirection, is there a way to redirect all traffic to https except one url?

(So I can use URL for the health check on http and all the rest on https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} /specific_controller/specific_method [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```